# Transparent container on half screen in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, mutter, xprop

Basically, I closed my laptop lid at night and normally it would go to sleep. But, in morning when I opened it, it didn't started at the login screen but on the page where I left it and was unresponsive. So, I again closed and opened the lid and this time it started normally.

After signing in, I was welcomed by a nearly transparent container in the right-half of my window.

1. It doesn't covers the top activity bar.
2. It doesn't interfere with any contents or clicks
3. `xprop` it gives **MUTTER GAURD WINDOW**
4. going to all apps hides it.

[image]

Notable: I had created a `go to desktop` icon using this https://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2018/10/add-show-desktop-button-ubuntu-18-10-18-04/ a few days back and it works fine. I wonder if it is creating the problem

**EDIT**
Looks like 'mutter gaurd window' was shown for anywhere on the desktop. So, the problem was like non-existent for xprop.

The problem was **solved** when I shrank a window by double clicking then dragged it all the way upwards the normally gives a glimpse of it getting maximised. And it removed that container too. I guess it could be an issue related to window resizing.

So, why is it happening? PS I haven't done a reboot but wanted to know about the issue

Comment: Please post your solution as an answer to your own question. Thank you! ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved when I shrank a window by double clicking then dragged it all the way upwards the normally gives a glimpse of it getting maximised. And it removed that container too. I guess it could be an issue related to window resizing.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem but a transparent screen from left. I solved it by using: Window + Left mouse (moving) and it disappeared.